# Spring Boot web server / RPC / CorDapp - making it work

Tags: spring-boot, rpc, corda

I’m new to Corda - I did BootCamp last week and completed certification test this week. But I’m missing some of the intricacies and struggling to get a Spring Boot web front end to an RPC interface.

I’ve been working through the yo-cordapp sample to try to understand it. (I realise it’s using the Corda web server rather than the Spring Boot web server, but no matter - it’s the detail of how to make web-RPC-CorDapp work that I’m looking for, not details of Spring.) There’s a comment in the index.html file saying

`GOING FORWARD WE RECOMMEND IMPLEMENTING A STANDALONE WEB SERVER THAT AUTHORISES VIA THE NODE'S RPC INTERFACE. IN THE COMING WEEKS, WE'LL WRITE A TUTORIAL ON HOW BEST TO DO THIS.`

Any sign of that tutorial yet, or alternatively something else that’ll lead me through learning how Spring Boot <-> RPC <-> my CorDapp fit together, in detail?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/manishchainThat/mycordawithspringboot

Basically , you will need separate project or module for spring in which you will add your cordapp as dependencies (see the build.gradle file).

**Points to consider:**

1. Add cordapp (states and flow jars) as dependencies in your gradle.
2. Create node Rpc Connection based on the corda server port (Rpc).
   3.Create RPC client or Web client to create API .The above example uses jersey you 
   can use other spring implementation of Restful .

Comment: Thanks Manish. In fact since my original post I've managed to take the 'spring-webserver' sample from Corda and coax it into interacting with my Cordapp. However, I'm new to IntelliJ and gradle and finding it confusing. What output(s) do I take from a project like this (yours or spring-webserver) which I can then copy onto my server (happens to be an AWS EC2 instance) and then run to get the Spring server up? With my Cordapp I can just copy the node folders and run the corda.jar - what's the equivalent here?

Comment: Aha... discovered that I can use `./gradlew bootJar` to build the jar and have got that up and running now on my server, interacting with the Corda node.

Comment: @Jonathan I hope it helped you .Please upvote the answer so that other members would find it relevant and helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the corda 4.0 release this is possible.. Please check https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/app-upgrade-notes.html#id4
for more information